I'm getting memory access errors while launching Battlefield 2042
Battlefield 2042 keeps pointing to a null memory address, as well as trying to access memory it doesn't own (c0000005). Since it's trying to write to a null address, that implies something went horribly wrong internally before it tried to do something.
I've tried with 2 different graphics cards and 2 different packages of RAM, and I've tried rolling back, updating, and reinstalling my graphics drivers, as well as attempting to run the game in safe mode.
When the game goes awry, it freezes my entire PC, and I have to forcibly restart it by holding the power button. I've spent literally 75 minutes NOT being able to play the game, and I just got it. I've tried reinstalling twice, and it never worked.
I ran the memory dump (.mdmp) file that the game spat out into the documents folder through winDBG to figure out what's going on, and put the output in a pastebin.
I desperately want to love this game, but not being able to play it really sucks, especially when it's a very nitty-gritty problem like this. I purchased the game on Steam and have my Steam account linked to my EA account.
I would love to answer any other questions that anyone has about my situation. Thank you so very much!
Specs:

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 745
Intel Core i7-6700 @3.4GHz
16 GB (2x8) DDR4, clocked at 2133 MHz (SK Hynix HMA41GU6AFR8N)
16 MB Swapfile, 5 GB Pagefile
Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.19045


Did you try to repair the installation? I dont know the EA Origin stuff but there should be an option to repair an installation from inside it. If that doesn't help, well... every single BF release in history has been buggy like sin upon release.

@Amarth Well, I tried repairing it a couple times in steam, but I couldn't find an option to repair in the EA app.
